# Transform current workspace variables into code

Tags: matlab, export, workspace

Sometimes I would rather not like to show my data to other people and therefore I need to modify it. When it is ready for export, I wish to export the workspace data, for instance a table, exactly as it is, for POSTING it here for instance.

I know the generate script function, and I feel the answer is somewhat related but it is not that, and publish is also not the command I require. How do I do that?

**UPDATE with example:**

How do I print a table as code?

```
%% Table example to export workspace

T={'A2P3';'A2P3';'A2P3';'A2P3 with (extra1)';'A2P3 with (extra1) and (extra 2)';'A2P3 with (extra1)';'B2P3';'B2P3';'B2P3';'B2P3 with (extra 1)';'A2P3'};
a={1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 }

T(:,2)=num2cell(1);
T(3,2)=num2cell(0);
T(6,2)=num2cell(0);
T(9,2)=num2cell(0);

T=table(T(:,1),T(:,2));

class(T.Var1);
class(T.Var2);

T.Var1=categorical(T.Var1)
T.Var2=cell2mat(T.Var2)

class(T.Var1);
class(T.Var2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since **Matlab 2014a** there is this new feauture:

> MATLAB now provides the ability to save workspace variables to a
>   MATLAB script. Once the script is saved, you can regenerate the
>   workspace variables by running the script. Click Save Workspace on the
>   MATLAB desktop and select MATLAB script (*.m) in the Save as type
>   menu. Alternately, use matlab.io.saveVariablesToScript to perform this
>   operation from the command line.

[**Documentation fo `matlab.io.saveVariablesToScript`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.savevariablestoscript.html)

If you don't have the new version, you will need to write your own I/O routine for your variables. It's quite easy to do that generic for numerical arrays, but it depends on the certain case.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, it is a table and contains numeric and string data. i have 2013b.

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly please post an example and how you'd like the code to look like in the end. But for tables with mixed content it's a complex task. If posting here is the only purpose, I'm not sure if its worth the pain. Probably better in a new question.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, i updated my question and found out i can upvote people at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

If Matlab 2014a is not available, I would use `gencode` from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24447-generate-m-file-code-for-any-matlab-variable)

Comment: does gencode support tables? it seems to be a rather intimidating piece of code with 3 tl;dr files. how much do i need to study it before i can use it?

Comment: @Easyquestionsonly: I don't think so, tables where introduced with matlab 2013b but the code is not maintained since 2009. You don't need to study the code, reading the documentation for `gencode` is enough.